# Sharepoint Modal box width issue overflowing

Tags: 2010, master-page, system-master-page

I have a problem with a custom master page I have designed for Sharepoint 2010 where the modal popup box is not wide enough and the elements are spilling off the side of the box.

This is the box that appears after having clicked on 'Add new item' or 'Add new announcement'.

Please see the attached screenshot showing this problem.

I thought I could counteract this by setting the site master as the custom master page I have made and using the default v4 system master page for the modal popup however when I do this, the custom master page does not show.

I have to set the custom master page to both the site and the system ones.

It would be cool to hear back from someone about this as this is really getting to me and causing me headaches at work :/

Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS4a0.jpg

Comment: from Google Chrome's inspect element or IE Developer Toolbar look for the css ms-dialog which dialog box use internally... You can play with it to fix the width issue!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check any elements in your master page that have been given a fixed width in your CSS as that can cause this exact behavior

Comment: Here's my custom CSS - can you see any issues with it?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4251284

Comment: You do indeed have lots of fixed widths in there but the one that concerns me is the `min-width: 700px;` on the BODY tag.  Try commenting that out and seeing if it changes the popups